# Facebook Social Plugin: How do I add an event handler for "View More" comments on the Facebook comment box?

Tags: javascript, facebook, dom-events

I have a Facebook app that has the Facebook Comments box embedded on it.

I want to know if there is any way to add a callback that gets fired when I click the "View xx More" comments at the bottom of the comments list. I want to trigger a custom block of code when users click on the "View xx More".

Similar to the block of code below for the `Event - comment.create`, I want to fire a callback when a user clicks on the more comments link.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function (response) {
    ntptEventTag('ev=FbComment');
if($("#facebookcomments .fb_ltr").length) $("#facebookcomments .fb_ltr").blur();
});
```

As far as I can see, from the [Facebook Javascript SDK page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/), it only has events like "user like", "user unlike", "post comment", and "remove comment".

Any help or information would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Is there any event handler for “View More” comments on the Facebook comment box ?

**No**

Comment: You're right on the part that there is no event for the "view more" action, but it would be great if you can tell me if/how you've overcome this.

Comment: You cannot. What do you want to achieve with event ?

Comment: I want to get the focus out from the comment iFrame after the comments finish loading. Why? Because on some versions of FF and on IE7, I get a dotted outline on the iFrame when there is focus on it, and the only way to remove it is to call blur() on the iFrame -- similar to what I've done for the comment.create event above.

Comment: Show your code, may be we can look for some workaround.
Also, I am saying again there's no event handler for 'view more'